# Accessing a selector only once per touch gesture

Tags: ios, core-data

I've a reload method which handles with highly sensitive core data and I want to implement, that the method can not be executed in parallel.

Is there a simply way to implement something like that?

**Update**

Maybe it's a different problem.

So I've a pinch-gesture and when a user is doing this gesture I want to execute a method only ONCE!

BUT if I'm simulating it right now in the iOS simulator, the method execution starts when a minimal pinch gesture is recognized and is fired as long as the user holds this pinch gesture.

Is this the default usage?!?!? How can I edit it, that the method is only fired once per pinch gesture independent of how long the user is holding this gesture etc.

Comment: The pinch gesture is a continuous gesture so it will call your action method multiple times. Within your action method you can check if the `state` property of your gesture recognizer (passed as a parameter to you) is set to `UIGestureRecognizerBegan` if you want to do some logic as soon as the gesture begins or `UIGestureRecognizerEnded` to do some logic when the gesture is done.

Comment: Ahh typo... I meant of course `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` and `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`. Sometimes I think StackOverflow doesn't compile my comments...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes there is. Check out the `@synchronized` directive: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocThreading.html

Answer (score -1):

andi1984,

Of course, you could require that the method only execute on the main thread. As in this example:

```
- (void) sensitiveMethod {

    // If necessary, rethrow on the main queue.
    if (!NSThread.isMainThread) {

        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock: ^{

            [self sensitiveMethod];
        }];
        return;
    }

    // body of your sensitive method here.

} // sensitiveMethod
```

Andrew